# Button only able to be pressed once?(Python tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

When I run the program it only recognizes one button press, is this due to bad code or something i didn't take into account? If anyone could help me figure this it that would be lovely, it could be something in the logic and if statements but im not sure.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def flow_control(text, state):
    if state == 1:
        state = 2 if text == 'Y' else 4

    elif state == 2:
        state = 3 if text == 'Y' else 4
        
    elif state == 4:
        state = 5 if text == 'Y' else 7

    elif state == 5:
        state = 6 if text == 'Y' else 7

    elif state == 8:
        state = 6 if text == 'Y' else 9

    elif state == 7:
        state = 6 if text == 'Y' else 8
    print(state)
    lab['text'] = LABEL_TEXT[f'state{state}']


LABEL_TEXT = {
            'state1':'''Do you have symptoms similar to cold, shortness of breadth, a cougth, 
                a temperatue higher than 38 degrees ar loss of smell or taste?''',
            'state2':'''Stay at home until you have results of your coronavirus test.
                  Is the result of your test positive?''',
            'state3':'''You can return after 24h of being syndrom free and it is 7 days since you got sick.
                Inform your study coach about your situation(voluntary). If the result of the test is still positive,
                stay home for 3 days. You can come out if you don't have any syndroms''',
            'state4':'Does someone in the household have fever or short breadth?',
            'state5':'Is the test of the family member positive?',
            'state6':'Stay home for 10 days',
            'state7':'Do you know that you had contact with domeone tested positive?',
            'state8':'Have you been in a risky region for the last 14 days?',
            'state9':'You can come to the office :)'
        }

state = 1

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500+200+200')
root.title('Should I stay or should I go?:)')

lab = ttk.Label(root, font=('Arial', 10), text= LABEL_TEXT[f'state{state}'])
lab.pack(fill='both')

yes_button = ttk.Button(text='Yes', command=lambda: flow_control('Y', state)).pack(side='left', fill='x', expand=True)
no_button = ttk.Button(text='No', command=lambda: flow_control('N', state)).pack(side='right', fill='x', expand=True)
#clean_button = ttk.Button(text='ccccc').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How would i be able to make the "Quiz" go on instead of stopping

Comment: `state` is passed as an argument to `flow_control()`, then it is treated as a local variable.  So updating it inside the function does not update the global one.  So every time the function is called, the passed value of `state` will always be 1.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the program it only recognizes one button press, is this
> due to bad code or something i didn't take into account?

The problem can be fixed.

- On line 7, `state` parameter in `flow_control` function.

  ```
  def flow_control(text):
  ```
- On line 8, add global in `flow_control` function.

  ```
  global state
  ```
- On line 55 and 56, remove `command` keyword `state` on `Button` widgets.

  ```
  command=lambda: flow_control('Y')
  ```

You're ready to go.

Selecct y, y n, etc. Do whatever button you're selected.